# Trying to find the number of rows in a particular sheet

Tags: vba, excel

**Update:**   *I figured out my error -  the variable sheetRange needed the Sheets("Schedule"). added to it as well*

Sorry for the inconvenience.
I have a relatively simple problem in that I am trying to use VBA to find the number of rows in a particular sheet. I am getting a pop up box that just says 400 and am not really sure where my syntax is off.

```
Sub PhxCheck()


Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, numofRows As Integer
Dim top As Range, bottom As Range, sheetRange As Range
Dim phxContract As String, contractID As String


Set top = Sheets("Schedule").Range("A3")
Set bottom = Sheets("Schedule").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
Set sheetRange = Range(top, bottom)
numofRows = sheetRange.Rows.Count

Cells(30, 1).Value = numofRows
End Sub
```

The error happens when I add Sheets("Schedule"). to the top and bottom ranges.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nevermind I found out that you have to also add Sheets("Schedule") to the sheetRange variable. Very silly error, my mistake.

Comment: good catch. Just so you know, the reason you have to do that is Range with no qualification infers the active sheet. Alternatively, you could have set a variable as the sheet. `Dim ws as WorkSheet` `Set ws as worksheets("Schedule")` `ws.Range...`

Comment: Thanks justnS, appreciate the explanation. I'm a relative novice at VBA so comments like yours help out a great deal.

Comment: Jean-Francois Alright, didn't realize that was the protocol, but I will make sure to do so in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code a lot and avoid using redundant variables which will limit mistakes.

All you need is:

```
With Sheets("Schedule")
    Cells(30, 1).Value = .Range("A3", .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
End With
```

I understand you solved your problem yourself, but perhaps the above will help you or someone else searching for a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm always looking for more efficient ways to do things.